# Where can I find the official DTD specification

Tags: w3c, dtd

Where can I find the official DTD specification? Unlike say XPath and XML Schema, I cannot seem to find specification for DTD on the W3C web page, nor did I manage to find it via google.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's part of the XML specs. [You can find them here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-doctype).

Depending on your needs, and for completeness' sake: The DTD definition from the XML specs is a subset of the DTD definition that's part of [SGML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) (ISO 8879:1986), which [Quentin already referenced in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612437/1071311).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is part of [ISO 8879:1986](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=16387), which is available for a fee.

Comment: 198 Swiss Francs according to that link. :(